ST_AsMvtGeom returns null
I have a line that is produced in a bit strange way.
I don't want to go into details how it is produced and why that way. I would just like to understand the problem.
So, the line starts at point A, gets to point B and then goes back to point A.
In postgres, it is written as LINESTRING, although the shape itself can be considered as rectangle with witdh of zero.
When I try to produce vector tile that would capture that line, it doesn't show up since ST_AsMvtGeom returns null for this geometry on all zoom levels.
Same function & setup I have works for all other lines.
Question is - why?
PS.
ST_IsValid returns true for the line.

The issue can be re-produced with this SQL
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_AsMVTGeom(
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0,1 1,0 0)'),
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)),
4096, 0, false));
-> null

With LINESTRING (0 0,1 1) the MVTGeom is not null.
The geometry LINESTRING (0 0,1 1,0 0) is valid, but it is not simple as can be tested with ST_IsSimple. I believe it would not disturb you if the geometry in the MVT geometry would be linestring A-B instead of A-B-C, but unfortunately I do not know how to get it. There is not a function like ST_MakeSimple in PostGIS.
ST_MakeValid does not alter the A-B-A geometry. The common trick to simplify with zero tolerance does not help with ABA linestrings.
st_simplify(
'linestring (0 0,1 1,0 0)',0);
-> null

Keep collapsed version:
st_simplify(
'linestring (0 0,1 1,0 0)',0,true);
-> "LINESTRING(0 0,0 0)"

I could not answer your question but I hope that this helps others to find out some simple trick.
EDIT:
This is dirty but seems to work
select ST_AsText(
ST_As
ST_Intersection(
ST_GeomFromText('linestring (0 0,1 1,0 0)'),
ST_GeomFromText('linestring (0 0,1 1,0 0)')))

-> "LINESTRING(0 0,1 1)"


Thank you for your thoughts! To follow up, do we know where the actual issue is? Is it that ST_AsMvtGeom doesn't work with non-simple lines? Or is it because geometry is somehow understood as zero width rectangle? Or what might be the case and where?

One idea is...I could do a check if last leg of a line ends at the same point as the first leg starts and then either delete last leg if number of vertices is =<3 or change geometry to polygon if number of vertices is >3.

Maybe the issue is in the simplification. I believe that simplification is a part of the workflow of making MVT. But at least ST_Simplify is not supposed to remove the end and start points of a linestring.

hm...thats a good point! if simplification is a part of ST_AsMVT and if it uses Douglas-Peucker algirithm with a tolerance less than distance between A and B then that would actually remove point B and reduce line to a point. And since that is a line with lengrh zero, it might be left out.

I was able to reproduce this problem by creating a series of randomized points with a coordinate system of EPSG 4326. While some functions check whether operations are carried out with different coordinate systems, ST_AsMVTGeom doesn't appear to.
For an example, trying an operation with ST_Within with different coordinate systems returns an error.
SELECT id, geom, value FROM sample_tiles WHERE ST_Within(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y))


yields:
ERROR:  contains: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Polygon, 3857) != (Point, 4326). 0.000 seconds. (Line 8).

(where z,x,y is some tile position over the random data)
If you do a similar operation with ST_AsMVTGeom

SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(geom, ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y)) AS geom FROM sample_tiles


The query returns null, and doesn't return an error. And if you add an ST_Transform, you get content:
SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(geom, 3857), ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y)) AS geom FROM sample_tiles

